# Get/access the latest state of application from store in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm pretty sure there's a lot of times we need to get the latest state/value of application which is managed by the global store(ngrx) in Angular. I've noticed since Angular 4(or 5), they don't have `value` or `getValue()` to make it accessible. What we need to do(I believe) to get the latest state/value from the store is that add another subscription so that the `BehaviorSubject` oriented store emits the value it keeps. However, I can't help feel that this isn't the right way. Whenever we need to get the latest state/value of the application, add another subscription to the store? That sounds a bit non-sense to me. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use `ngrx-store`. Read this [**blog post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)

Comment: @Aravind I'm currently using ngrx/store as I described above. My question is why ngrx/store doesn't have 'value' or 'getValue()' unlike Redux does.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of a time that you need the latest state? There may be a way to refactor it.

Comment: @DongBinKim, subscription in a way is like a function call, so @Hayden is correct, you should use `take(1).subscribe()` combination

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I understand `take(1)` would cut the subscription after the one time subscribing but adding another subscription whenever we need the latest state/value of the application is the right/efficient way and the way Angular is going for?

Comment: @DongBinKim, it's not Angular, it's RxJs mechanism. See [this section](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observables-as-generalizations-of-functions) that compares subscription to a function call which will help you understand that pattern better

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com We manage the state of the application by using `ngrx/store` which is implemented based on redux concept but what I'm asking is that why `ngrx/store` doesn't have anything like `getState()` in redux, which leaves me no choice other than to add another subscription to get the latest state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribing to the store is the correct way to get the latest state

```
let state;
store.take(1).subscribe((s) => {
    state = s;
})
console.log(state);
```

Reduce the number of times you do this by putting your action logic inside your reducer functions (where you already have access to the state)

Comment: I understand they designed Angular(ngrx/store) this way but I still don't understand why they would make us add another subscription to get the latest state.

Comment: There was a `value` property at one point but it was removed.
https://github.com/ngrx/store/commit/19d9fe3f92bd57ffae541039109f6e6fcd686295

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. I'm just wondering what made them decide to remove it.

Comment: There were discussions in original the ngrx/store issues but they disappeared when the project was archived